# Differences between purge and delete files?

Tags: oracle, file, unix, purge

I have looked it up but haven't been able to find many differences between purging and deleting a set of files. Is there more to PURGE than simply BACKUP AND DELETE?

EDIT: Specifically, this is about trace files and log files in Oracle

Answer (score 3):

Purge runs on a regular basis. It delete things that marked as delete. You can set up criteria. For example, you can set criteria that to remove all the rows have a flag as delete, and remove those rows from a table.

Delete removes the rows on going. For example, if you have a work queue, and the tasks will be finished after the queue, you can delete those rows since they are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Purge Process

Purging is the process of freeing up space in the database or of deleting obsolete data that is not required by the system. The purge process can be based on the age of the data or the type of data.

Archive Process

Archiving is the process of backing up the obsolete data that will be deleted during the purge process. During the archive process, data will be moved from the main transactional tables to the backup tables

Comment: I have a question regarding this, Does DR strategy includes the data that are purged already ?

Answer (score 0):

--some situations allow only soft DELETE, means the record is not deleted permanently and can be revovered later.

-- PURGE is for deleting permanently and cannot be recovered later.